# Simple explanation of how to clean up unmanaged resources in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I have an app using MVVM Light which launches another app that I need to stop when the user closes the main app down.

I have created a Dispose() method that frees up resources, but what I don't understand is where I **call** Dispose().

For example, I noticed in the Application class definition there are is: `public event ExitEventHandler Exit;`

Can I add something to my App (see code below) that is triggered when the app is about to exit?

(I know there are many other question on this topic but they all seem to presume more c# knowledge)

App.xaml.cs...

```
namespace Module.Config
{
    public partial class App : Application
    {
        static App()
        {
            DispatcherHelper.Initialize();
        }    
    }
}
```

MainWindow.xaml...

```
<Window x:Class="Module.Config.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:ignore="http://www.ignore.com"
        mc:Ignorable="d ignore"
        Height="640" MinHeight="600"
        Width="800" MinWidth="800"
        Title="Config"
        DataContext="{Binding Main, Source={StaticResource Locator}}"
        Closing="Window_Closing"
        >

    <Window.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="../Skins/MainSkin.xaml" />
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Window.Resources>

    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Margin="3">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="200"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ContentControl Content="{Binding Side}" Grid.Column="0" />
        <ContentControl Content="{Binding SelectedModule}" Grid.Column="1" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs...

```
namespace Module.Config
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Closing += (s, e) => ViewModelLocator.Cleanup();

            Messenger.Default.Register<DialogMessage>(
                this,
                msg =>
                {
                    var result = MessageBox.Show(
                        msg.Content,
                        msg.Caption,
                        msg.Button
                        );

                    msg.ProcessCallback(result);
                });

       . . . . . 


        private void Window_Closing(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
        {
            /*
            I want to call Dispose() within AvigilonViewModel.cs 
            */
        }


    }
}
```

AvigilonView.xaml...

```
<UserControl x:Class="Module.Config.Views.Modules.AvigilonView"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Module.Config"
        xmlns:ignore="http://www.ignore.com"
        mc:Ignorable="d ignore"
        DataContext="{Binding Avigilon, Source={StaticResource Locator}}">

    <Grid>
    .....
```

AvigilonView.xaml.cs...

```
    namespace Module.Config.Views.Modules
    {
        public partial class AvigilonView : UserControl
        {
            public AvigilonView()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
            }
        }
    }
```

MainViewModel.cs......

```
namespace Module.Config.ViewModel
{
    public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {
        private ViewModelBase m_selectedModule;

        public ViewModelBase Side
        {
            get { return ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<SideViewModel>(); }
        }

        public ViewModelBase SelectedModule
        {
            get { return m_selectedModule; }
            set
            {
                m_selectedModule = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("SelectedModule");
            }
        }

        public MainViewModel()
        {
            Messenger.Default.Register<PropertyChangedMessage<object>>(this, (r) =>
            {
                if (r.PropertyName == "SelectedNode")
                {
                    if (r.NewValue is RedSensor)
                    {
                        SelectedModule = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<SensorViewModel>();
                        (SelectedModule as SensorViewModel).Sensor = r.NewValue as RedSensor;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        SelectedModule = r.NewValue as ViewModelBase;
                    }
                }
            });
        }

    }
}
```

AvigilonViewModel.cs....

```
namespace Module.Config.ViewModel.Modules
{
    public class AvigilonViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {
    ....

        public Dispose(){
            /* code to get rid of unmanaged resources */
        }
    }
}
```

ViewModelLocator.cs...

```
namespace Module.Config.ViewModel
{
    public class ViewModelLocator
    {
        static ViewModelLocator()
        {
            ServiceLocator.SetLocatorProvider(() => SimpleIoc.Default);

            if (ViewModelBase.IsInDesignModeStatic)
            {
                //SimpleIoc.Default.Register<IDataService, Design.DesignDataService>();
            }
            else
            {
                //SimpleIoc.Default.Register<IDataService, DataService>();
            }

            SimpleIoc.Default.Register<AppState>();
            SimpleIoc.Default.Register<MainViewModel>();
            SimpleIoc.Default.Register<SideViewModel>();
            SimpleIoc.Default.Register<AvigilonViewModel>();
        }


        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the Main property.
        /// </summary>
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Performance",
            "CA1822:MarkMembersAsStatic",
            Justification = "This non-static member is needed for data binding purposes.")]
        public SideViewModel Side
        {
            get
            {
                return ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<SideViewModel>();
            }
        }


        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the Main property.
        /// </summary>
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Performance",
            "CA1822:MarkMembersAsStatic",
            Justification = "This non-static member is needed for data binding purposes.")]
        public AvigilonViewModel Avigilon
        {
            get
            {
                return ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<AvigilonViewModel>();
            }
        }

    ....
```

I've also noticed the line `Closing += (s, e) => ViewModelLocator.Cleanup();` in the above. I have tried adding a method called `Cleanup() to AvigilonView.xaml.cs and AvigilonViewModel.cs but it doesnt seem to be getting called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can handle the `Closing` event of your MainWindow and do the processing there.

**XAML**:

```
<Window Closing="Window_Closing">
```

**Code behind**:

```
private void Window_Closing(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
{
   // Clean up your resources here.
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much. However I still can figure out how to reference my viewModels within the Windows_Closing method (in order to call Dispose) E.g. if I have an XAML file that starts: `<UserControl x:Class="Module.Config.Views.Modules.AvigilonView"....` How to I figure out the name of the object for this class?

Comment: If you have an instance of View, you can access it's ViewModel by accessing `DataContext` property of View. eg - `avigilonView.DataContext as AvigilonViewModel`.

Comment: Thanks, but what do you mean by `instance of View`? Do you mean I should create an instance of View? I tried that but got: `The type or namespace name 'View' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)` For avigilonView it says `The name 'avigilonView' does not exist in the current context`

Comment: I am not sure what are you upto. Post some relevant code what View you are talking about? You gotta show some code. Right now it's very hard to comment without seeing your code. (Question only asks for where to put cleaning up code).

Comment: I've added what I think is the relevant code to my question - please let me know if you need more.

Comment: Where you create an object for `AvigilonView`? Also post code for `ViewModelLocator.Cleanup();`, what Cleanup() is doing?

Comment: I understood it was getting created by teh MVVM Light framework when it sees it in AvigilonView.xaml.cs

Comment: Go to definition of `Cleanup` and see what it's doing?

Comment: It is empty. So this is not going to help me after all. Still cant figure out how to reference the object for avigilonViewModel so I can call Dispose()

Comment: You must be creating the `avigilonView` and `avigilonViewModel` somewhere. Where is that?

Comment: I dont recognise anywhere. However maybe it is in ViewModelLocator - I have posted it above I will try using the property `Avigilon` mentioned there to see if that works.

Comment: ok finaly figured it out. Within Window_Closing() I added 
`var theAvililonViewModel = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<AvigilonViewModel>();`
`theAvililonViewModel.Dispose();`